# Why is this SQL statement not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Can somene please tell me why is this SQL statement not executing?

The error I am getting is 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Sood' at line 1'.

The table name(`tbl_authordescription`) and the column name(`ad_authorname`) are correct as I have checked it atleast 50 times.

```
$bd_author = 'Piyush Sood';

$checkauthorquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_authordescription WHERE ad_authorname = $bd_author";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($checkauthorquery, $connection_psfriend) or die(mysql_error());

if($Recordset1){
    echo 'The author exists.';  
}
```

Comment: Looks like missing quotes.

Comment: Text fields should be compared using quotes around.

Comment: And as usual for such questions: Don't use mysql functions, but mysqli functions or PDO (*sigh*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your author name in the query is not encapsulated. Try adding single quotes around it.

```
$checkauthorquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_authordescription WHERE ad_authorname = '$bd_author'";
```

Better yet, checkout [prepared statements](http://php.net/PDO).

Comment: Ok thanks that solved my problem.But some statements do work without these quotes. Why is that?

Comment: When saving data like strings to the database, special characters like spaces are interpreted and the next word is read as a command--this is also how basic SQL injection works. Adding the quotes tells the engine that your sending an explicit value to be saved and no interpretation is made. If your saving something like an integer, float or expression value, there is no need for quotes as they are interpreted as themselves no matter the circumstance. If your working with new code, save yourself the trouble and switch to prepared statements. PDO or mysqli at the very least.